# Loading a new CSV in Azure Blob Storage to SQL DB

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory, bcp

I am loading a csv file into an Azure Blob Storage account. I would like a process to be triggered when a new file is added, that takes the new CSV and BCP loads it into an Azure SQL database.

My idea is to have an Azure Data Factory pipeline that is event triggered. However, I am stuck as to what to do next. Should an Azure Function be triggered that takes this CSV and uses BCP to load it into the DB? Can Azure Functions even use BCP?

I am using Python.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to please check below link. Basically you want to copy new files as well the modified file for that single copy data is used full. Use event based trigger(when files in created) instead on schedule one.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6365/incremental-file-load-using-azure-data-factory/